# Should I throw an exception or return false?

Tags: c#, exception, tdd

I'm developing a simple service locator in C# using TDD.

At the moment, I've created a `TryAddService` method that looks like this:

```
    public bool TryAddService(Type type, object service)
    {
        if (service == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.services.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(service.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        this.services.Add(type, service);

        return true;
    }
```

My question is, should I be returning false in all these cases? Or should I throw an exception?

My customers in this scenario would be other developers.

Comment: Since it returns a boolean value, there would be no need of throwing an exception, simply return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As informally agreed, whenever you use TryXXXX pattern, your method must be always successful, but return actual success result as boolean. If you'd like to throw and Exception, then just remove the "try" word from your method name.

On the top, if you follow the TryXXXX pattern, I recommend you to add a try-catch block, to ensure your method really always succeeds:

```
public bool TryAddService(Type type, object service)
{
  if (service == null)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (this.services.ContainsKey(type))
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(service.GetType()))
  {
    return false;
  }

  try
  {
    this.services.Add(type, service);
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to wrap whole function in a `try.. catch`. Because if line `this.service.Add` will throw exception of some other reason then expected, then this exception will be swallowed.

Comment: @Fabio, that's the whole point of the TryXXXX pattern -- NEVER throw an exception, regardless of any problems, even if the whole system crashed! And the potential exception is not concealed -- the function returns false in the case of any exception during Add method.

Answer (score 0):

I use this scenario :
I have a class that all services return this class named (MyReturn for example)

```
public sealed class MyReturn<TEntity> : IDisposable
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public string SysException { get; set; }
    // and etc...
    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

Now your service:

```
public MyReturn <bool> TryAddService(Type type, object service)
{
    if (service == null)
        return new MyReturn <bool> {Message = "Your messgage"};
    //and etc...
    return new MyReturn <bool>();
}
```

In your form u check Message , if null or empty, you have no error ....
You can customize it...

Answer (score 0):

> My customers in this scenario would be other developers.

Are you expecting consumers of your class will register types conditionally?

```
if (TryAddService(typeof(IService), new Service1()))
{
    // Added successfully - what to do next
}
else
{
    // What here? Try another service?
}
```

Or developers will just register implementation they need and rely on the fact that `TryAddService` will throw an exception during application startup.

```
TryAddService(typeof(IService), new Service1());
```

As developer I want to receive quickest feedback as possible if I did something wrong. Throwing exception during application startup (where usually service registration is done) will be quickest possible feedback. Unless you will use generics with constraints, which will provide feedback early during compile time.

If developers don't have logic for failed registration, then return nothing, but throw custom exception with descriptive message

```
public void TryAddService(Type type, object service)
{
    if (service == null)
    {
        throw new RegisterServiceException($"Can not register null for type '{type.FullName}'");
    }

    if (this.services.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        throw new RegisterServiceException($"Service for type '{type.FullName}' already registerd.");
    }

    if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(service.GetType()))
    {
        throw new RegisterServiceException($"Type '{type.FullName}' should be assignable from service of type '{service.GetType().FullName}'");
    }

    this.services.Add(type, service);
}
```